# Post request not rendering in handlebars

Tags: express, sequelize.js, handlebars.js

I am building an app for a project that is using a post request with the findAll method that filters certain properties in the user model within the database to find divers with desirable skills and certification levels. I can see the data console logged in the terminal, so I know I am retrieving the desired users as an array of objects. However, I am unable to see anything being rendered to the page via handlebars. Sorry in advance, this is my first post and I'm still pretty new at this.

I have tried changing the method to a create method and using a get request to retrieve the data, however I would need to use a body in this scenario, which is not compatible (i think) with a get request and I could not create in this manner as I'm not actually creating a new user, therefore it would return an error as username and email are allowNull:false. This was suggested by a tutor

Here is my post request:

```
router.post('/', withAuth, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const conditions = {
        certifications: {
            [Op.substring]: req.body.certifications,
        },
        gas_mixes: {
            [Op.substring]: req.body.gas_mixes,
        },
        ow_dive_totals: {
            [Op.gte]: parseInt(req.body.ow_dive_totals)
        },
    };
    if (req.body.photography) {
        conditions.photography = true
    }
    if (req.body.active_efr) {
        conditions.active_efr = true
    }
    if (req.body.active_O2) {
        conditions.active_O2 = true
    }
    if (req.body.active_dm) {
        conditions.active_dm = true
    }
    if (req.body.active_instructor) {
        conditions.active_instructor = true
    }
    console.log(conditions)
    try {
        // Get all divers that match search criteria
        const userData = await User.findAll({
            where:
                conditions
        }
        );
        const users = userData.map((user) => user.get({ plain: true }));
        console.log(users)
        console.log('Data passed to template:', { users });
        res.render('matches', { users })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.stack)
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});


Here is the js:

let matchingFormHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    let certificationsVal = document.querySelector('#certification-form').value.trim()
    let gas_mixesVal = document.querySelector('#gas-mixes-form').value
    let ow_dive_totalsVal = document.querySelector('#ow-dive-form').value
    let photographyVal = document.querySelector('#photography-form').checked
    let active_efrVal = document.querySelector('#efr-form').checked
    let active_O2Val = document.querySelector('#O2-form').checked
    let active_dmVal = document.querySelector('#dm-form').checked
    let active_instructorVal = document.querySelector('#instructor-form').checked

    const data = {
        certifications: certificationsVal,
        gas_mixes: gas_mixesVal,
        ow_dive_totals: ow_dive_totalsVal,
        photography: photographyVal,
        active_efr: active_efrVal,
        active_O2: active_O2Val,
        active_dm: active_dmVal,
        active_instructor: active_instructorVal
    }

    const response = await fetch(`/api/divers`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    if (response.ok) {
        console.log('RESPONSE OK')
    } else {
        alert(response.statusText)
    }
}



document
    .querySelector('.form')
    .addEventListener('submit', matchingFormHandler);



Here is the handlebars:

{{log users}}
{{#each users as |user|}}

<h2>{{user.username}}</h2>
<h2>{{user.gas_mixes}}</h2>
<h2>{{user.certifications}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You're making a fetch request from the front-end and expecting a json back right? Well, handlebars is a server-side template package. It looks like you are sending a view file back to the fetch request.